# Keep user input, even when app is suspended/closed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to make a simple note taking app for Windows Phone 8.

My question is: 
How do I make the text that the user puts into the textbox stay inside the textbox 
even if the app is suspended or deactivated?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using IsolatedStorage for saving your user's notes inside phone's memory and try getting them back when your app is launched again. 
Here is a link that will help you get through IsolatedStorage
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[Another Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/699426/Isolated-Storage-in-Windows-Phone)

### Example code from the second link:

**Storing:**

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings isoStoreSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    int integerValue;
    int.TryParse(Entier.Text, out integerValue);
    //store the integer
    isoStoreSettings["IntegerValue"] = integerValue;
    //store the string
    isoStoreSettings["StringValue"] = chaine.Text;
}
```

**Retrieving:**

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings isoStoreSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    int integerValue;
    string stringValue;

    //Retreive The integer
    if (isoStoreSettings.TryGetValue("IntegerValue", out integerValue))
    {
        Entier.Text = integerValue.ToString();
    }

    //Retreive the string
    if (isoStoreSettings.TryGetValue("StringValue", out stringValue))
    {
        chaine.Text = stringValue;
    }
    isoStoreSettings.Save();
}
```

Comment: I added the basic code from the CodeProject-link. In case the link should die, there's still an example here. :)

Comment: Do I have to activate namespaces for this?

Comment: using System.IO.IsolatedStorage; this will do.